# General question on definitions of graphs and their complements.

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say I have a graph $G$ defined by $V_G=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}, E_G=\left\{\{v_i,v_j \}:P(i,j)\right \}$, for some predicate $P$.

Is it then true that $E_\overline G=\{\{v_i,v_j\}: \neg P(i,j)\}$?

The definition my professors gave me of $E_\overline G$ is $E_\overline G=K_n\setminus E_G$.

How can I prove the equivalence of definitions?

Comment: I don't see why not...

Comment: I editted my post to reflect the reason of my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that it is not true, this leaves us with two cases.
For ease of writing I will denote the set $ \{ (v_i,v_j) | \neg P(i,j)\}$ as $S$

1. Either there is some element of $E_{\overline G}$ that is not a member of $S$ or
2. There is some member of $S$ that is not a member of $E_{\overline G}$

In case 1:  WOLOG, assume that $(v_1,v_2) \in E_{\overline G}$ and $(v_1,v_2) \notin S $.  Thus, $\neg \neg P(1,2)$ is satisfied, and therefore $P(1,2)$ is satisfied $\implies (u_1,v_1) \in \{(v_i,v_j) | P(i,j)\}=E_G$, a contradiction.

In case 2:  WOLOG, assume that $(v_1,v_2) \in S$, yet $(v_1,v_2) \notin E_{\overline G}$.  Here, $\neg P(1,2)$ is satisfied thus $(v_1,v_2) \notin E_G \implies (v_1,v_2) \in K_n \setminus E_G=E_{\overline G}. $ Again, this is a contradiction.

I think this works as a proof.  Let me know if something doesn't seem right.